# Excel 2013 macro - ACTIVECELL.OFFSET (1, 0).SELECT

Tags: excel, excel-2013

Excel 2013 macro - in **ACTIVECELL.OFFSET (1, 0).SELECT** how do I specify the number of rows to offset from a value (say $S$4 = 6) in my spreadsheet?

Comment: Don't use activecell, use the desired cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to answer your question:

```
ACTIVECELL.OFFSET (ActiveSheet.Range("S4"), 0).SELECT
```

But you should avoid the `.SELECT`  See [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) on how to do that.

the method you are choosing is problematic, as it will slow the code

Comment: Ooooh using a cell as the argument.

Comment: That worked, thanks.  I left in .select as after reading the "post" it would not concern me.  I tried this solution first. However it exposed a logic error (unrelated to your solution) and that will be a thorny one to fix. What I'm trying to do is update a specific row (X) in a list by copying and pasting the revised data X lines down from the top.

Comment: That is a new question. In a new post ask your question.  You will want to show some data and more of the code. @jgb

Comment: I was just commenting, not asking a 2nd question.  I fixed the logic bug, so this macro now works like I want.  Thanks again @ScottCraner

Comment: I am glad it works, please mark as correct, by clicking on the gray/green check mark by the answer. @jgb

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the value in a cell and use it as the offset you can use something like:

> ACTIVECELL.OFFSET (sheet1.range("s4").value, 0).select